# How to center div in navbar (not with space-between)

Tags: html, css, navbar

I would like to center the R on my navigation bar so that it is just above the tip of the polygon. I can't do it the text sometimes disappears. Also, maybe my clip-path is embarrassing, I admit that I don't really know. :(

If anyone has an idea, thank you in advance ^^

**EDIT: 18:51 -> I've modified my clip-path because of bad sizing.**
HTML :

```html
<div class="navbar">
        <div class="clubBar">
            <nav>
                <ul><li><a class="navbarLink" href="https://club.rosewood-rp.net/">Se connecter au club</a></li></ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="logoCentre">
            <h1 class="Rlogo">R</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="rightNavbar">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="navbarLink" href="index.php"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Acceuil</a></li>
                    <li><a class="navbarLink" href="discover.php"><i class="fas fa-trees"></i> Découvrir le serveur</a></li>
                    <li><a class="navbarLink" href="news.php"><i class="fas fa-newspaper"></i> Actualité</a></li>
                    <li><a class="navbarLink" href="https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=825396450"><i class="fab fa-steam"></i> Workshop</a></li>
                    <li><a class="navbarLink" href="https://discord.gg/zj9Nmqt"><i class="fab fa-discord"></i> Discord</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: #111111;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10vh;
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 80%, 50% 100%, 0 80%, 0 0);

  color: white;
  font-family:"Loew Bold";
  font-size:16px;
  font-style:normal;
  display: flex;
  flex: auto;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

/* Barre de naviguation gauche */

.clubBar {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0.4%;
}

/* Barre de naviguation droite */
.logoCentre {
  color: white;
  font-family: "Posterama 2001 W04 Black";
  font-size: 4vh;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#c80000, #ed1c24);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

/* Barre de naviguation droite */
.rightNavbar {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0.4%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css

```
.logoCentre h1 {
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 50% 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found another solution than flex.
I've used **position: relative** & **absolute** with **right** & **left**.
Here is my css :

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: #111111;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10vh;
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 80%, 50% 100%, 0 80%, 0 0);

  color: white;
  font-family:"Loew Bold";
  font-size:16px;
  font-style:normal;

  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Barre de naviguation gauche */

.clubBar {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0.4%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 1vh;
}
.clubBar:hover{
  background: linear-gradient(#707070, #4f4f4f);
}
.clubBar a { 
  color:white;
  font-size: 2vh;
  margin: 0 0.5vw;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.clubBar a:link {
  font-family: "DINNextLTPro-Condensed";
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Barre de naviguation droite */
.logoCentre {
  color: white;
  font-family: "Posterama 2001 W04 Black";
  font-size: 4vh;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#c80000, #ed1c24);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 0px;
  left: 50%;
}

/* Barre de naviguation droite */
.rightNavbar {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0.4%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 1vh;
}
.rightNavbar ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}
.rightNavbar li{
  list-style-type: none;
   margin: 0 0.5vw;
   font-size: 2vh;
}
.navbarLink:hover{
  background: linear-gradient(#707070, #4f4f4f);
}
.rightNavbar a { color:white }
.rightNavbar a:link {
  font-family: "DINNextLTPro-Condensed";
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I just added a `line-height: 0` to your `logoCentre` class, tell me if it was what you were looking for !

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: #111111;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  clip-path: polygon(0 15%, 0 0, 100% 0, 100% 15%, 50% 25%);

  color: white;
  font-family:"Loew Bold";
  font-size:16px;
  font-style:normal;
  display: flex;
  flex: auto;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

/* Barre de naviguation gauche */

.clubBar {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0.4%;
}

/* Barre de naviguation droite */
.logoCentre {
  color: white;
  font-family: "Posterama 2001 W04 Black";
  font-size: 4vh;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#c80000, #ed1c24);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  line-height: 0;
}

/* Barre de naviguation droite */
.rightNavbar {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0.4%;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
        <div class="clubBar">
            <nav>
                <ul><li><a class="navbarLink" href="https://club.rosewood-rp.net/">Se connecter au club</a></li></ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="logoCentre">
            <h1 class="Rlogo">R</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="rightNavbar">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="navbarLink" href="index.php"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Acceuil</a></li>
                    <li><a class="navbarLink" href="discover.php"><i class="fas fa-trees"></i> Découvrir le serveur</a></li>
                    <li><a class="navbarLink" href="news.php"><i class="fas fa-newspaper"></i> Actualité</a></li>
                    <li><a class="navbarLink" href="https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=825396450"><i class="fab fa-steam"></i> Workshop</a></li>
                    <li><a class="navbarLink" href="https://discord.gg/zj9Nmqt"><i class="fab fa-discord"></i> Discord</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi, it's much better thanks, but not yet. I've modified just a little bit my clip-path because of bad sizing. It's look like this http://prntscr.com/s5tm53

Comment: Try some adjustment with some margin-left percentage on your Rlogo class and it should work !